# ERROR: Caught exception [ERROR: Unsupported command [addSelection |]

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, nunit-2.5

I am using selenium web driver with C# and on trying to select an item on the available list I am receiving an error as:

> ERROR: Caught exception [ERROR: Unsupported command [addSelection |

Can someone help me with this? Any workaround?

What I am trying is to select an item from a list which is on the left side and then click on the button (>) to move it to the right side.

Comment: A quick search on Google (bear in mind I know nothing about Selenium) for "Selenium Webdriver AddSelection" revealed a bunch of hits - seems you may need to do something with the Select class.  https://www.google.com/search?source=ig&rlz=1G1ACGW_ENUS358&q=selenium+webdriver+addselection&oq=selenium+webdriver+addselection&gs_l=igoogle.3..0.1338.7418.0.7564.33.15.1.17.17.0.200.1660.10j4j1.15.0...0.0...1ac.1.Ec-jW-3_73A

Comment: could not find any helping me on this, so have posted on this website.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the error because not *everything* in the IDE can be converted into the WebDriver API's.

You have to think about this logically, and not rely on the IDE to start generating this code for you.

The C# bindings have a `SelectElement` class, inside `OpenQA.Selenium.Support` namespace, you'll need to add a reference to the `WebDriver.Support.dll` assembly.

It encompasses 'common' use cases for `select` elements. With this, you can probably mimic the behaviour of `addSelection`. I haven't used the IDE so am not sure what that command is intended to do, but you can simply do something like:

```
IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.Id("a"));
SelectElement select = new SelectElement(element);
select.SelectByValue("2");
select.SelectByText("George");
select.SelectByIndex(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Select selectbox= new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("MY ID")));
            selectbox.selectByIndex(2);