# Selenium - ERROR: Caught exception [ERROR: Unsupported command [clickAt]

Tags: java, selenium, testing, automated-tests

I'm trying to export selenium IDE test to Eclipse with JUnit but I get this:

> ERROR: Caught exception [ERROR: Unsupported command [clickAt]

I know about some limitations in Selenium IDE:
[ERROR: Caught exception [ERROR: Unsupported command [addSelection |]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16097534/error-caught-exception-error-unsupported-command-addselection)

I'm hoping that someone can help me with that command `clickAt` because using only `click` doesn't work for me.

I need to drop down the list and choose from it:

```
<div id="select2-result-label-12" class="select2-result-label" role="option">
    <span class="select2-match"></span>
    THOMSON
</div>
```

The ID is changing dynamically, so I used the html class to get it and `contains`, like this:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='select2-result-label'[contains(@text, 'THOMSON')]")).click();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your xpath selector should look like this:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='select2-result-label'][contains(text(), 'THOMSON')]"))
```

If you're looking for a really good guide for xpath selectors I highly recommend you [this article](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/xpath,-css,-dom-and-selenium-the-rosetta-stone/).